# Not able to display previous data in ListView in Android while using notifyDataSetChanged()?

Tags: java, android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

I am not able to display previous data displayed in ListView when using `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of adapter. Used String array (even tried `ArrayList<String>`) for storing data.

I have tried almost all answers relevant to this question but couldn't get the correct result. Any help will be appreciated.
In my code I am trying to modify the String array.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    String countryArray[];
    Button add;
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    ListView list,newList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        countryArray = new String[3];
        countryArray[0] = "India";
        countryArray[1] = "USA";
        countryArray[2] = "England";
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countryArray);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCheckList);
        newList = list;
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        countryArray[2] = "belgium";
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**CustomAdapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context;
    String[] values;
    View rowView;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int val, String[] objects) {
        super(context,val,objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, parent, false);
        }
        TextView tx = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.iv1);
        tx.setText(values[position]);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.Image1);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the previous are not being displayed? Like "India',"USA"?

Comment: yes when i m trying to add another data item or even modifying the data item its only displaying the latest data item which i modified i.e. "belgium"

Answer (score 1):

Please check this line in your code.

```
rowView = convertView;
```

And when you put `notifydatasetchanged()` method, rows will update and refresh. So put this method in `getView()` after fetch data.

Please check [this link](http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-notifydatasetchanged.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can override the onResume method which belongs to Activity. You need to add this method to your activity.

```
    @Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countryArray);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: how would reinitializing the adapter w/a new object help?

Comment: how does onResume() will help me? bcoz i m using button to add data item

Answer (score 0):

Change your getView() method of custom adapter like this..

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            rowView = convertView; //you are missing this line
            if(convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, parent, false);
            }
            TextView tx = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            tx.setText(values[position]);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.Image1);
            return rowView;
    }
```